# Multiple stripe payment attempts by different people. Should they share the same `clientSecret`?

Tags: stripe-payments, singleton, payment, lazy-initialization

## Stripe `PaymentIntent`

The stripe example app suggests to create a `PaymentIntent` when the payment form is loaded.

At the same time, the documentation says that you should create the `PaymentIntent` as soon as you know how much to charge to the customer and use the same intent to avoid multiple charges.

## Alice and her friends travel together

Let's assume this scenario: Product is "lond distance trips" with a high-ticket payment. (> 3 000 EUR/USD) and there is a high change that the person who selects the product sends a payment link to somebody else to do the payment (potentially to another traveller). Let's call Alice the trip-lead and Alice, Bob and Charlie the travelers.

Discard the idea that Alice pays a part, Bob another part... Not the example to analyze.

The idea is that Alice tries to pay in full but if her card fails, asks Bob or Charlie to do the full payment. After the full payment they will arrange nubers between them.

To facilitate that, the system prepares a quotation for Alice with a payment link. Alice can pay clicking the link, but she can also share the link with Bob and Charlie. The link contains the quotation ID so there's no chance to faking the amounts and what not.

In fact the link sends to a "validation page" before the checkout: "This payment is for Alice, trip xxx, amount xxx, [pay now]".

## When should the `PaymentIntent` entity be created?

I can imagine multiple scenarios:

1. **Singleton early-initialization**: Create the `PaymentIntent` when the quotation is created and the payment link generated for the first time, and use the very same `PaymentIntent` loading it.

   - Pros: A single remote singleton entity tracks payment trials from all: Alice, Bob and Charlie, acting as a protection to avoid duplicated payments by accident.
   - Cons: This can lead to waaay long stale payment intents that never get to the checkout page if people were just curious about the amount without intention of paying.
2. **Singleton lazy-initialization**: When the checkout page is loaded for the first time, create the payment intent and save the ID to the quotation, so subsequent checkouts will reuse the already-initialized id.

   - Pros: As in "1.", a single entity tracks payment trials from anyone trying to pay that specific quotation that all of them share.
   - Cons: Additional coding logic if we want to protect against race conditions if both Alice and Bob (or Charlie) load the checkout for the first time at the same millisecond to avoid creating two objects and breaking the singleton thing.
3. **Multiple, one for session**: When loading the checkout, create a new payment intent for each coockie, so Alice will have her payment intent, Bob his own, Charlie also his. Additionally Alice in the PC and Alice in the mobile could potentially generate different `PaymentIntent`s as they might have different cookies.

   - Pros: Follows the documentation when it says "create a new payment intent for each session", but I don't get if they were meaning "for each different product-purchase".
   - Cons: Tracking is cumbersome: If Alice tries to pay and fails, then passes the link to Bob "hey, Bob, pay this for me" and it fails, then passes the link to Charlie and so... we will have to track for multiple PaymentIntents separately which is *not* nice.
4. **Multiple, volatile**: Create a `PaymentIntent` at each checkout page load.

   - Pros: Follows the demo: Cheate intent by ajax on page-load.
   - Cons: Tracking is completely crazy and potentially leaves a lof of stale intents around if they go and reload and reload.

## The intuition

My intution says that the preferred scenario would be **singleton, lazy-initialization**. I can see a good tracking in a single place for all the attempts for the same quotation, avoiding to create too many stale items like in the first option.

In fact in this scenario, if we find a stale item will effectively mean that someone "touched the checkout but did not pay" which is the proper intention of leaving a stale `PaymentIntent` there.

Neverhteless I wonder what happens from the security point of view if I share the same clientSecret across multiple people and locations (maybe Alice is in Barcelona while Bob is in Madrid and Charlie in Paris).

## Questions

- What of the 4 approaches should be used and why?
- If I choose the **singleton, lazy-initialization**, is there any penalty/security/risk for using the same `clientSecret` across multiple browsers, devices and IPs?

Answer (score 0):

You've laid out the options really nicely here and covered the pros and cons pretty well.

I was leaning toward agreeing with option 2 (singleton, lazy-initialization), but since the customer/payer is conceptually shifting I think option 3 (Multiple, one for session) might be preferred. You'd track in your quotation system whether one of the associated payment intents has been paid and then cancel the others and block further creation. You can build extra assurances about avoiding duplicate payments in the race condition scenario by using [separate auth & capture](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later), only capturing once you've ensure you didn't end up with two authorized payment intents at once.

If you want to go with your singleton approach, to get help with questions about risk when re-using the payment intent across geographies like this I'd suggestion reaching out to Stripe's [support team](https://support.stripe.com/contact) with this detailed explanation of your preferred flow.